# ffmpeg, how to cut to exactly at the start and end time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

According to [this article](https://ottverse.com/trim-cut-video-using-start-endtime-reencoding-ffmpeg/) you can only cut *the time*, but not specify when to cut from the original video. So the end time will *always be wrong*. You need to calculate each time on the timeline when your video will end.

e.g. `-ss 01:30:40 -to 03:03:05` will cut your video in the wrong order, because it starting the calculation not from the `00:00:00` of the video, but from the `-ss 01:30:40`

Is there a workaround for this?

example command:
`ffmpeg -ss 00:14:15 -an -i  "2022-05-30.mp4" -to 01:30:40 -crf 23 -c:v libx264 PART1.mp4`

I will lose `14:15` minutes here, it is clearly a bug.
I need to extract `14:15` from the end time to get the correct time of the result video. When it comes to multiple video-editing it's so annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FFmpeg is behaving exactly as it is called. Your main issue is the lack of understanding of the complex FFmpeg option structure. Specifically, you are mixing `-ss` **input** option and `-to` **output** option. Cutting to the chase, try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:14:15 -to 01:30:40 -i "2022-05-30.mp4" -an -crf 23 -c:v libx264 PART1.mp4
```

The documentation is very clear on what type of options they are (input/output/global). Some of them, including `-ss` and `-to`, can be either input or output, depending on their placements. Misplacing them results in an unexpected result like you experienced.

There are some finicky timing condition issues in FFmpeg, but I don't think your case falls under them.

Comment: Although I disagree the documentation is clear.
On -ss and -to form they should have said these:

If you want to trim the video from 5 to min 10, you should put -ss and -to together
If you want to trim the video after specific mark for 5 min, without attaching the timeline to the video use this:
- ss (input file.mp4) arguments -to (output file mp4)

This one is very clear. Something like these, but in more better english
I have read multiple threads on stackoverflow about these and NOONE could clearly explain these. Only my thread explained everything clear, with your answer.

Comment: For the record, I said "complex" not "clear". As it is a free open-source project which is going strong for 20+ years with ever so evolving digital multimedia scenery, it is bound to be complex and it actually amazes me how well they can package all its features in one coherent package. As with any open-source project, if you feel there is a deficiency in documentation, it is your responsibility as a user to contribute and make it better.